# How to split a string in a list and use the output to compare with a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose my dictionary contains

```
{'one': '1','two': '2', ..., 'hundred': '100'}
```

and my list contains

```
[['for 30']['for thirty']]
```

I want to split the strings in the list as :

```
[for],[30] and [for],[thirty]
```

Then I want to use the `'thirty'` to compare with the corresponding entry in the dictionary and get `'30'` as output.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('dict.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
   k, v = row
   d[k] = v

with open('test_term.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
```

Comment: `[['for 30']['for thirty']]` = `['for 30', 'for thirty']`? `{'one'='1','two'='2'........'hundred' = '100'}` = `{'one': '1','two': '2'........'hundred': '100'}`? `[for],[30]` = `['for', 30]`?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that comparison? Do you need to split the list and strings in that format or you just want to extract the second word of each string?

Comment: @safwan I have edited your question to make it more readable. Please check if it is according to your needs. Then try to make it even more clearer by answering to my questions.

Comment: I hope you realize that the "dictionary" you start with is not a dictionary, but causes a syntax error. If you want a dictionary, replace those equal signs with colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Python! You should really read some basics, like how to declare a list and a dictionary.

I guess what you were trying to do is that:

```
# this is how you format a list
pair_list = ['for 30', 'for thirty', 'for 1', 'for two']
# this is how you format a dict
resolve_dict = {'one': '1', 'thirty': '30', 'hundred': '100'}

# iterate the list two strings at a time
for idx in xrange(len(pair_list)):
    # example in comments
    # pairs[idx] == 'for 30'
    splitted = pair_list[idx].split(' ')
    # splitted == ['for', '30']
    number = splitted[1]
    # number == '30'

    # pairs[idx + 1] == 'for thirty'
    splitted = pair_list[idx + 1].split(' ')
    # splitted == ['for', 'thirty']
    word = splitted[1]
    # word == 'thirty'

    # comparison
    if resolve_dict[word] == number:
        print 'hurray?'
```

Comment: it says pair_list is not defined...how do i fix it?

Comment: my bad. edited. but really, look at the code. you have a variable pair_list referenced but not declared.